# Qt VTK link fails

Tags: qt, vtk

I am trying to build a simple Qt app with the VTK libraries included, but I am getting a link error:

> The Reg....A functions are unresolved (like RegOpenKeyExA) referenced
>   from vtksys.lib.

I think that I have Advapi32.lib linked.

Am I supposed to specify ASCII in the build somehow or is a library missing or what?

Answer (score 0):

What does your CMakeLists.txt look like? You should have a line like:

target_link_libraries(YourProgram QVTK ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

Answer (score 0):

What is your compiler used to build VTK? And Qt? Are them identical? It seems most linked problems between Qt and VTK are due to mismatching library files.